# How to write query statement for SQLite Database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm implementing an SQLite database. In the database I'm storing objects of type `Contact` whose definition is below. The method `getContact()` is supposed to take an `id` and return the corresponding `Contact` object in the database. But this isn't working. When I debug it, the control is getting stuck on the line, after which the app crashed.

```
  Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME_DEFAULT,KEY_NAME,KEY_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

I have a very basic understanding of SQLite and can't figure out what's wrong here. Please help.

**Contact class**

```
package com.example.nirvan.diary30;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Contact
{
String nameDefault;
public String name[];
public Bitmap image[];
public int id;

Contact(int id, String name,String arrName[],Bitmap arrImage[])
{
    this.id=id;
    this.nameDefault=name;
    this.name=arrName;
    this.image=arrImage;
}

}
```

**getContact() in DatabaseHandler.java**

```
Contact getContact(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME_DEFAULT,KEY_NAME,KEY_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();


    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1) ,convertStringToArray(cursor.getString(2)) , backConverter(cursor.getString(3)));

    return contact;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
**Log**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.nirvan.diary30, PID: 6937
                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: image (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, nameDefault, name, image FROM contacts WHERE id=?
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1238)
                                                                          at com.example.nirvan.diary30.DatabaseHandler.getContact(DatabaseHandler.java:136)
                                                                          at com.example.nirvan.diary30.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:87)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1933)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:685)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2156)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1138)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1132)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1105)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1396)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1501)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should edit your post and include a complete stack trace of the exception from logcat.

Comment: @Karakuri  Done. I've included the relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `query()` statement looks fine. You need to check that [`cursor.moveToFirst()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) returned `true` though. It returns `false` if the `cursor` is empty. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow) for more details

Try this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
   Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), 
            convertStringToArray(cursor.getString(2)),
            backConverter(cursor.getString(3)));
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Comment: Just to explain further. A cursor after a query is unlikely to be null, that is if the query returns nothing the cursor is still created but with a row count of 0 (i.e. if you do cursor.getCount() it will return 0). There are many reasons why, for instance a ListView showing nothing should be an option that doesn't require special/additional coding.

Comment: @AmrAbed  Ok i tried that and it's still not working. Like I said, I debugged it and after I step-into the `que  ry` statement...the app crashes. I have edited my question and added the log. Please have a look.

Comment: `no such column: image`. Looks like an error with your `create table` statement not the query. Check for spelling errors or maybe you forgot to include the image column

Comment: Yes, you were right. There was a mistake in my create_table statement . Though now I have a completely new error. But that's not for here. Thanks.